# How to push a file to Heroku that isn't in your version control?

Tags: security, file, version-control, heroku, push

I'm deploying my first app on Heroku, and I want to push a file which isn't in my version control (my `database.yml`). How to do it?

Comment: why is it not in your version control? This is the sort of thing that goes into your version control.

Comment: Because I have the database password in it.

Comment: do you use dedicated pg server? why you need to supply password to heroku?

Comment: No, I use a shared server. The thing is that I actually don't need to set it. I just set it because I figured it isn't secure otherwise.

Comment: You are the owner of your database, and in shared database - You can't change your password. You may be able to get support to do it if you logged a ticket although they'll probably want a valid reason.

Comment: Does that mean that my database on Heroku already has a password? If that's the case, then great, because I don't care what the password is, I just want my database to have it.

Comment: yes, if you look at the output of heroku config you will see a SHARED_DATABASE entry which looks like a URL - that has the username and password in it to your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If it was another type of file, you can always use S3 and pull it from there, but this is a file your app needs to start, so you need it on git.

Comment: How do I set the password, then? I thought it's usual practice that it's ignored, just for that reason. I'm not really a security freak, but everybody says that you should have a password for your database.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure if ERB works in my database.yml file, since I'm using Haml. When I tried before, it didn't work, and I was using a gem that was enabling it (but only when I pull it through one of his methods). So my problem is that I don't know a way to check if `password: <%= ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>` sets password to the content of `DATABASE_PASSWORD` variable, or if it sets the password to `"<%= ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>"`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is NO, you can do Importing and Exporting Your Data (db), but single file you have to place in git, that's good way or use amazon s3